# How to add and access custom php code in Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami

I need to add some of my own php files to an existing Wordpress site (from Bitnami) so it can be accessed from a 3rd-party service. I don't need to access anything from Wordpress in my code, but I need my code to be accessible from a url for 3rd-party services.

Like this:

https://myWordPressSite.com.  <- normal WP site

https://myWordPressSite.com/myCustomDirectory/generateSerial.php  <- my code
https://myWordPressSite.com/myCustomDirectory/doSomething1.php  <- my code
https://myWordPressSite.com/myCustomDirectory/doSomething2.php  <- my code

How can I add my directory of code to the Wordpress file structure, and how to access it from a URL?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Just reworded question a bit.

Comment: What exactly is the problem - does Bitnami not allow you to simply upload your files via FTP or something similar?

Comment: I can upload the files, I just don't know how to access them from a URL once their uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was much simpler than I thought, or any of the other answers presented here.

The answer is to just add a directory of my own code inside the Wordpress home folder.

In the case of a AWS/Lightsail/Bitnami/Wordpress package, the home directory is:

```
/opt/bitnami/wordpress
```

So I created a directory and put my code in it..

```
/opt/bitnami/wordpress/myDirectory
/opt/bitnami/wordpress/myDirectory/generateSerial.php
/opt/bitnami/wordpress/myDirectory/doSomething.php
```

And it was then accessible from a url like:

```
https://myWordPressSite
https://myWordPressSite/generateSerial.php //etc
```

One small catch is that some Wordpress packages and some other Bitnami packages are laid out a bit different, so check on your specific installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a $_GET OR $_POST to the header as a plugin for WordPress.

You will need a header of the plugin

```
/*
Plugin Name: name
Plugin URI: http://www.com/
Description: test
Version: 1.0
Author: your name
Author URI: http://www.com/
*/
```

**The first part of the code would be. The code you put in here would show in the header when each page is call**

```
function test_head() {
    echo $_GET['name it some thing']; 
    echo $_POST['name it some thing'];          
}
```

**To call the function you need to add this line of code**

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'test_head' );
```

To learn more about add_action you can read it at
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

After you a *Activate the plugin*
You can now call your web site with GET or POST base on what you added to the header.

By doing it was a plugin you can use the WordPress backbone function

Good Luck
Karl K

Comment: Thanks, but I need to add several php files and be able to access them from a normal url.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your theme's root folder called `myCustomDirectory` and place your php file inside that.

then add to your functions.php the following:

**This will handle the Rewrite Rules:**

```
add_action('init', 'custom_add_rewrite_rule');
function custom_add_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^myCustomDirectory/generateSerial.php', 'index.php?generateSerial=true', 'top');
}
```

**This will handle the [Wordpress Query Vars](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/):**

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'generateSerial';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

**This will tell wordpress to pull the correct file:**

```
function load_custom_template($template){
    if(get_query_var('generateSerial') ){
         $template = get_template_directory() ."/myCustomDirectory/generateSerial.php";
    }

    return $template;  
}

add_filter('template_include', 'load_custom_template');
```

**make sure to flush your rewrite rules when you are done by going to: Settings > Permalinks and clicking 'save changes'**

Comment: you can add multiple files by following the syntax

Comment: This looks interesting, but I need to add several php/js/css files that all rely on each other...basically a small, self-contained app that needs to exist on the main site. I'm not sure this mechanism will work.

Comment: its either this or your htaccess file.